# Adding and removing twitter bootstrap tabs/pills

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use bootstrap's built in tabs in my site, but I need users to be able to add or remove tabs themselves. I've seen several demos of jqueryUI tabs that allow the user to add or remove them, and I know that bootstrap's tabs are jquery themselves, so I know it should be a pretty easy script to add that functionality but I just can't figure it out. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tabs are activated individually](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs), so you should be able to simply add/remove the element from the DOM and call `$().tab('show')`.

Let's say you have existing tabs:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="existingTab">..</div>
</div>
```

Example of adding a new tab:

```
$('.tab-content')
    .append(
        $('<div></div>')
            .addClass('tab-pane')
            .attr('id', 'newTab')
    );

$('#newTab').tab('show');
```

This will make a new tab appear.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I'm not sure how to apply it. Basically I'd like to have a button much like in any browser, that when you click it, a new tab appears with containing certain content. I've tried implementing the code above a couple different ways now, and none seem to add a tab (or do anything for that matter). Can I trouble you for a few more minutes of your time?

Comment: @Dave [Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26ybT/1/)  that has a more thorough example of what I answered.. You'll notice clicking on tabs doesn't change them, this is a jsfiddle issue - it will work in the wild.